# How to use spring spEL inject serverlet context path to a bean property?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I heard that spEl can inject servlet context to it's bean property.

I'm using xml config style.

could you give me an example?

Comment: Where did you hear that and what are you trying to achieve?... because I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. Maybe you can post some sample code explaining what you have, and what you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you heard is correct. You can access servletContext in any bean available under WebApplicationContext from [Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html). 
You can define it in config file(which is loaded under webapplicationcontext) and access as:

```
   <bean id="myClass" class="abc.def.MyClass">
<property name="context" value="#{servletContext}"/>
```

```
   public class MyClass{

   private ServletContext context;

public void setContext(ServletContext context){
    this.context = context;
}

....
```

}

Comment: You can also pass a property from servletContext instead of the whole thing:


   ... value="#{servletContext.contextPath}" ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using webmvc, you can access the servlet context in `@Controller`s via the `HttpServletRequest`:

```
public ModelAndView theController(HttpServletRequest request ...){
    ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
}
```

Aside from that, you can `@Inject` the ServletContext about everywhere, even in your entities. The interesting question is: what are you trying to achieve? Please clarify what you want to do, so that we can understand where the problem is.